# E-commerce with React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, e-commerce

I want to build an e-commerce app with react. Please help me on these topics below..

- The best **plugins** for UI design and animation.
- How can I **render a different version of my website** in different devices?
- Best **payment Gateway** to use.
- Which **slider** will be the best for showing the products.
- ***The most important*** can anyone please suggest me the best **web content diagram** and the **database structure**.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I can recommend you [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) for payment. I'll look into other topics you need as well.

Comment: First, SEO should be a big priority. Then you will need some server-side rendering solution. This can be accomplish without any frameworks, but I recommend using Gatsby or next.js.

Comment: Thanks Arthur Brito for your suggestion..